# access 2016 selection of records in the subform depending on the value selected by the user in combibox. error 3075 obtained

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am programming on access 2016  where in I have created a form with a subform that contains data from a table. Now I have inserted a combi box to this form. I want only those records to be presented whose timestamp is equal to the timestamp selected by the user in the combibox.I have written a vba code, but I am receiving a 3075 error. Please let me know what is the error in my code
I have used the following code:

`Private Sub CboTimestamp_AfterUpdate()
Dim myTimestamp As String
myTimestamp = "SELECT * FROM master_demand_table where ([timestamp] = " & Me.Cbotimestamp ")"
Me.Master_Demand_table__subform.Form.RecordSource = myTimestamp
Me.Master_Demand_table__subform.Form.Requery
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

A combobox always returns text, so convert to a Date/time value:

```
myTimestamp = "SELECT * FROM master_demand_table where ([timestamp] = TimeValue('" & Me.Cbotimestamp "'))"
```